# Groovy type definitions

Tags: groovy

```
class GroovyClass {
  def aVariable

  void setAVariable(aVariable)
  {
      this.aVariable  = aVariable;
  }
}
```

My understanding was that we don't need to specify the type of a variable in a groovy class. But Groovy compiler complains if I declare 'aVariable' , why isn't it considered as a typeless variable with default accessibility ? Should every variable be defined with a def in Groovy both local and class ? Why is it that the function definition doesn't have to begin with a def ? and when I'm passing in a variable to the setter, it doesn't need any def in there ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That code works fine.  What do you mean by *"Groovy compiler complains"*?

You can define that function with a `def` if you wanted, and it would return `aVariable` (as that is what the assignment operatop returns), however, it wouldnt be following the standard for Java Beans in that setters should return null

Given that however, I can run:

```
a = new GroovyClass()
a.aVariable = 3
```

And it works fine

#### Edit

Basically, it's all down to the Groovy parser.  The parser expects some sort of list of 1..N keywords defining it's type or visibility, and then a name for the variable.  So the following are all valid:

```
class OkA {
  def aValue
}

class OkB {
  private aValue
}

class OkC {
  private String aValue
}
```

But you cannot just (with the current parser) say:

```
class BadA {
  aValue
}
```

Thinking about it, there's no reason I can currently think of for this restriction (as you can declare vars without `def` in Groovy), but the restriction is there, so you need to type `def` when defining class attributes.

Comment: Why can't I just say, aVariable .. do I always need to say def aVariable ?

Comment: @Phoenix Because just a variable there wouldn't make sense.

Comment: @Phoenix You have to say `def variable` as that's what the parser expects for an attribute definition.  Updated answer...

Comment: Thx is it the same for functions too ? do I need to say def test() or can I just say test() ??

Comment: You need to say `def` or an actual type (like `String`) or a visibility (like `private`) or `static`. The same as with attributes